# Error Pegasus package: TypeError: highly_variable_features() got an unexpected keyword argument 'consider_batch'

Tags: python, rna-seq

I am using Pagesus package to analyze my single cell RNA sequencing data. I have encountered the following error using the Pegasus package for single cell analysis. The function that is giving me the error seems to be:

```
highly_variable_features(data, consider_batch=True)
```

and the error is

`TypeError: highly_variable_features() got an unexpected keyword argument 'consider_batch'. after executing`

I am very novice with using python and this package. I haven't been able to find any explanation when looking through Github and Pegasus package tutorials.

I appreciate your advice on this

Regards,

Comment: Hey, you should provide some example code and maybe explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment: 
what I have done is: assigned my parameters to data: 
data = pg.aggregate_matrices(sample_dict, attributes = ['Type'], default_ref = 'hg19')  and then ran pg.qc_metrics, and pg.qcviolin(data, plot_type='gene', dpi=300) Then filtered data and I identified robust genes, but when I am getting to "highly_variable_features" genes I get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pagesus docs for this function: `highly_variable_features` do not mention keyword/parameter you passed in and thats how you getting that error.

Please look at this docs:
https://pegasus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pegasus.highly_variable_features.html?highlight=highly_variable_features

You should read docs more carefully, and try to learn basics Errors in Python and where they come from. This will help in the future to solve errors like this.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me, so I have assigned my parameters to data:
data = pg.aggregate_matrices(sample_dict, attributes = ['Type'], default_ref = 'hg19')
 and then ran pg.qc_metrics and violin plot: pg.qcviolin(data, plot_type='gene', dpi=300)
Then filtered data and I identified robust genes, but when I am getting to "highly_variable_features" genes I get the error

Comment: In their tutorial they are using the consider_batch=True
https://pegasus.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/_static/tutorials/batch_correction.html

Comment: Current Version is 1.6.0 and you sent a link to the 1.1.0 version ? So which one is it ? which version of the package you have?

Comment: @FVG Do not expect that tutorial from 2020 is up to date with API of 2022